# Makefile two variants of one executable dependent on make run

Tags: makefile

I am having a lot of trouble with figuring out how to make it so that I can make two executables for client dependent on how I run make.  When running just "make" I want client to be like so:

```
client: client.o open.o close.o
    gcc -g -o client client.o open.o close.o
```

and then when I run "make normal" I want client to be like this:

```
client: client.o
    gcc -g -o client client.o
```

I just have no idea how to go about doing this, I have been at this for a while and haven't found anything that is simple and helpful.  The entire makefile is below to put it all in context.

```
all:    client host tstWrappers

client: client.o open.o close.o
    gcc -g -o client client.o open.o close.o

client.o: client.c
    gcc -g -c client.c

host: host.o
    gcc -g -o host host.o

host.o: host.c
    gcc -g -c host.c

tstWrappers: tstWrappers.o open.o close.o
    gcc -g -o tstWrappers tstWrappers.o open.o close.o

tstWrappers.o: tstWrappers.c
    gcc -g -c tstWrappers.c

open.o: open.c
    gcc -g -c open.c

close.o: close.c
    gcc -g -c close.c


clean:  
    rm -f client host client.o host.o tstWrappers tstWrappers.o open.o close.o
```

Comment: Does `client.o` need to change how it was compiled depending on the "mode"? Or does that object file not need to change?

Comment: `client.o` does not need to change only the end `client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do here is likely just to duplicate the target:

```
client: client.o open.o close.o
    gcc -g -o $@ $^

client-normal: client.o
    gcc -g -o $@ $^
```

and then run `make client-normal` to generate a `client-normal` binary.

(Notice that I replaced the manually listed output and input files with the appropriate [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to avoid duplication.)

If you wanted to use `make` and `make MODE=normal` (or similar) then you could do this instead:

```
ifneq (normal,$(MODE))
EXTRA_OBJECTS := open.o close.o
endif

client: client.o $(EXTRA_OBJECTS)
    gcc -g -o $@ $^
```

Comment: I figured out a variant on this a little ago, yours is a little more clean, thanks for the help :)